# Switching Views/layouts

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a problem that I can't seem to find the solution to.

I have an app that loads the `main.xml` file on startup, of course. In it are several buttons, and I want the buttons to take me to a different XML file. I just used `setContentView(R.layout.newlayout.xml)` method for that, and it works great.

The problem comes in after that. If I reference any of the buttons or other objects in the new layout, the app won't even finish loading before it errors out and closes on the emulator. **However, if I take all references to objects out, the app runs fine.**

I can navigate *TO* the new layouts, but their buttons can't do anything. Do I need to create a separate Java file for each layout? Or am I doing it all wrong? I'm trying to be as specific as I can. I suppose you could say I need to have different **"pages"** in my app as a website would.

Comment: Posting your code would allow us to quickly localize the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anyone out there with the same problem and *haven't* figured out how to do it, as I said in my comment on ylebre, my Coworker and I have finally discovered how to do it. First off, we added

`implements OnClickListener`

to the class, after

```
extends Activity
```

then, we created a new java file, and at the beginning of the file it called

```
setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
```

instead of main. Then, we made a button as follows:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01;
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then later in the code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button01:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, NEWJAVAFILE.class));
                break;

        }
    }
```

And that's it! We just copied and pasted that code into NEWJAVAFILE, changed the names and such, and we were able to navigate freely back and forth. As ylebre said, all of the code for the new activity is in the NEWJAVAFILE.java. OH and don't forget to add the name of the java file to the manifest inside the  tags:

```
<activity android:name=".NEWJAVAFILE">        
    </activity>
```

it all seems so simple now!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is best solved using multiple java files, each one defining it's own android Activity.

While it is possible to have multiple layouts/views in a single activity, this will generally make the code more complex and harder to read/debug in the future. By having each 'screen' in its own file, it will be a bit easier to manage all the different views you need to juggle.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The past two or three hours I have been collaborating with another programmer in my office (who has no experience in Android, a little in Java from college, and a little in C#) and we FINALLY figured out how to get it all to work. I wish we would have checked your post first, because that's exactly what we ended up doing! I'll post an example in an answer for anyone else who has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The buttons and views only can refer to those mentioned in the current SetContentView() file..

u can test this by creating a button and initialising to an R.id... without setting the content view.. U will get a force close..

so if u change the XML file u shud initialise stuff again....